# Arrangements of triominoes and tetrominoes where each touches polyominoes of total area 4 times their own

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polyomino

Consider arrangements of triominoes and tetrominoes on a grid where each polyomino touches polyominoes of total area 4 times their own.  (Here "on a grid" means the vertices of the underlying squares have integer coordinates, and "touch" means share positive perimeter.)

It is not too hard to find a disconnected collection a triominoes and tetrominoes with this property, where each type of polyomino touches 4 others of the same area:

[image: 3-and 4-ominoes]

Is there a connected example?  If so, it is not hard to see that each triomino would need to touch exactly 3 tetrominoes, and each tetromino would need to touch exactly 1 tetromino and 4 triominoes.

https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0716.html